# Aligning numbers at decimal point angular ui grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am looking at aligning numbers on the decimal point in Angular UI Grid like below.

```
    11.293
      .89
233424
      .34345
```

I have had a few ideas including a cell template with three aligned divs and using transparent 0s.

Has anyone had any luck with this.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone attempt this before. You might try updating your question with an example of what you've tried so far to get some more specific help, also it sounds like something that could be a good task for a little custom directive. If you pass it the number it could break it up into divs as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best way is to select all the numbers with Javascript, then break them and encapsulate them in 2 span elements like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="int">11.</span><span class="float">293</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="int">233424.</span><span class="float">89</span>
</div>
```

Then you can assign a with to the elements and align the .int to right and .float to the left with css:

```
.int, .float{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.int{
    text-align: right;
}
.float{
    text-align: left;
}
```

This way the selection is ok and div and span doesn't disturb the meaning of your html5 code. Also, you do not deppend on a fixed width font.

Hope this works, if not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In my [component.ts](https://github.com/Sjord/summer/blob/align-numbers/src/app/number-list/number-list.component.ts) file I added a method splitNumbers, which converts each number into a array with the integer and fractional part:

```
splitNumbers() {
  return this.numbers.map(number => {
    let str = number.toString();
    return str.split(".");
  });
}
```

In my [component.html](https://github.com/Sjord/summer/blob/align-numbers/src/app/number-list/number-list.component.html) I added separate `<span>` elements to the integer and fractional parts. Don't use whitespace between the tags unless you want extra whitespace in your output:

```
<li *ngFor="let parts of splitNumbers()">
  <span class="integer">{{ parts[0] }}</span>.<span class="fractional">{{ parts[1] }}</span>
</li>
```

Then in [the CSS](https://github.com/Sjord/summer/blob/align-numbers/src/app/number-list/number-list.component.css) I set the integer part to inline-block, give it a width and make it align right:

```
.integer {
  text-align: right;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The result:

[image: list of numbers]

As you can see the last number is very small and written in scientific notation instead of expanded. So this doesn't work perfectly.